# TS6133 Typescript compiler is not checking the usage of nested object members

Tags: typescript

During Typescript development we are using `noUnusedLocals` in tsconfig.json to keep our code clean and remove unused local variables. Passing in complex objects to a method, the parameter object just gets checked on a top level basis, but not the usage of nested values like shown below:

```
class Test {
    main({
        obj
    }: {
        obj: {
            v1: string;
            v2: boolean;
        };
    }) {
        console.log('Foo');
        //console.log(obj.v2);
    }
}
```

shows the following error:

```
Test.ts:2:10 - error TS6133: 'obj' is declared but its value is never read.

2     main({
           ~
3         obj
  ~~~~~~~~~~~
4     }: {
  ~~~~~
```

Changing the code to this:

```
class Test {
    main({
        obj
    }: {
        obj: {
            v1: string;
            v2: boolean;
        };
    }) {
        console.log('Foo');
        console.log(obj.v2);
    }
}
```

does **not** point to the missing usage of `obj.v1`. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: That's the type declaration. Usually you don't use all members of an object in a function and usually you name your types. You would have to modify your objects and remove unused properties if this were possible.

Comment: `obj` is the "local", so why would `v1` and `v2` be checked? If you want those to be "requited" to be used, require them as parameters instead of the object that contains them.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not something that `noUnusedLocals` rule supports. It only checks if all local variables are being used on the scope, at a superficial level. That means that it doesn't go in deep inside those variables, when they are objects holding fields/properties.

And as far as I tell, there is no actual linter rule or language construct that does that. To be honest I don't even think it would be very efficient, since it will have to do a lot of checking in objects across project, objects of arbitrary nesting levels.

Thus, as suggested in a comment to the question, a possible approach would be to extract v1 and v2 as function parameters.